# Batch file that compares dates and outputs the latest

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a bat file that checks the date of two different files in different locations and base a copy of the results.  Haven't made any progress.  Help would be appreciated!
File1 c:\usr
File2 c:\temp
File2 is newer: start robocopy
Something like this.

Tried many different dir listings but nothing that always tells me the latest.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "filename1=c:\106x\zzq3.txt"
SET "filename2=u:\zzq3.txt"

FOR /f %%e IN ('xcopy /D /L /Y "%filename1%" "%filename2%"') do set "older=%%e"
ECHO %older%
FOR /f %%e IN ('xcopy /D /L /Y "%filename2%" "%filename1%"') do set "older=%%e"
ECHO %older%

GOTO :eof
```

The filenames I chose were simply test files. Alter as appropriate.

`xcopy` switches `/d` will copy if the first file iss later than the second; `/L` will create a list only, so no actual copying takes place; `/Y` "copies" without prompting.

Hence the `xcopy` report will be either `0 Files(s) copied` or `1 Files(s) copied` and the variable `older` will be set to `0` or `1`.

Comment: Wow, thank you!  Shoulda asked a day or two earlier.  Have a great one!!